# C++ pre-formatted text output for CMD?

Tags: c++

I am trying to pimp up the programs I wrote with fancy ASCII-Art,
I can't manage to display it on the console though, is there a way I can output
pre-formatted text, just as `<pre>` in HTML? I am using cout for most output.

```
 _____           _   
|_   _|         | |  
  | |  ___  ___ | |_ 
  | | / _ \/ __|| __|
  | ||  __/\__ \| |_ 
  \_/ \___||___/ \__|
```

Comment: Windows' `cmd` uses a monospace font. There should be no reason, apart of encoding, to have any sort of issue when displaying ASCII art. Are you referring to how you should encode the ASCII art in your source?

Comment: Is your console set up with a fixed width font?

Comment: @Asu the problem is especially that I get errors like "\ being an escape sequence" and lines not fitting together because Newlines arent set up properly. With <pre> you can preformat your text just like above, and it prints it just as that, without the need of adding /n or endl;

Comment: Use [C++11 raw string literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals)?

Comment: `<pre>` in html is unformatted text, so is text output in console, except some simple formats like color, bold (in Unix terminal)... The width is always fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
std::string const asciiTest = R"~(
 _____           _   
|_   _|         | |  
  | |  ___  ___ | |_ 
  | | / _ \/ __|| __|
  | ||  __/\__ \| |_ 
  \_/ \___||___/ \__|
)~";
```

Within a RSL you don't need to escape special characters, and newlines are preserved.
This is a double-edged sword though: identation and leading/trailing newlines are *also* preserved, so you need to take care of them.

Comment: Thanks, this worked and was what I was looking for, couldnt find it with google :)